# Capture UI router's state change when there is no change

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, state

I would like to use UI router's `$stateChangeStart` to capture state change when transiting from '/foo/bar' to '/foo/bar':

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function() {
    // ...
});'
```

Essentially, I would like to capture when the link for the current state was clicked so I can force reload.

Comment: Could you add the code with the link and your state definition ?

Comment: `<a ui-sref="/foo/bar">Go</a>` :)

Comment: `<a ui-sref="foo.bar">Go</a>` Typo. It doesn't matter how I utilize the link. I want to be able to capture if app is trying to navigate to the current state and reload everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$stateChangeStart` event get fire only when the browser url gets changed. While redirecting to same state there will not be any change in `State`.There is no way to track changed state same as that of the previous one. That's why what you want, won't be possible to achieve using `$stateChangeStart` event.

I'd suggest create your own directive that will fire a code of checking state on click of it.

**Directive**

```
.directive('uiSref', function($state){
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attr){
      element.on('click', function(event){
        if(attr.href.substring(1, attr.href.length) === $state.current.url)
           //from here you can track state haven't changed 
           console.log("Success")
      });
    }
  }
})
```

[**Example Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/ejrva3EH62gJ7aSyMEZN?p=info)

If you just want to reload controller then you could simply mention `reload: true` on state level.

It's not an appropriate way to do it. Its work around from me.

Comment: `if (element.attr('ui-sref') === $state.current.id)` works better, because `$state.current.url` returns just the `/bar` part, without the `/foo`. Thanks.